# how will i create a lambda function (named : evenword) that will return true if length of x (lambda function variable) is even

Tags: python

```
a_list = ['this','is','a','sample','message']
even_word  = lambda x: 
b_list = filter(even_word,a_list)
print(b_list)
```

How will i create a lambda function (named : evenword) that will return true if length of x (lambda function variable) is even

Comment: Well, how do you write a `def` function that does the same?  Start with that, and then look in a "lambda" tutorial for the conversion information.  When you've finished trying to do that, *then* you'll have a Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 1):

Most pythonic, don't name lambdas and don't use filter when list comprehensions will do (and just use `&`)

```
a_list = ['this','is','a','sample','message']
b_list = [val for val in a_list if not len(val) & 1]
print(b_list)
```

Comment: Why the `& 1` ?

Comment: `& 1` masks all but the last bit... showing I have a bug from not reading close enough.

Comment: Okay, now last bit zero, negated, means even.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
even_word=lambda x:len(x)%2==0
```